# How to display firebase background message on screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, provider

How can I display the data from FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage() from Firebase inside a widget in flutter. Currently I am using provider to retrieve my messages from the database and each time a foreground message is received, I update my provider and the Consumer() widget gets updated and the new message is displayed. This is how I have done it, by setting FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen() in initState() method, I just want to know how to rebuild the widget when a background message is received, then the message can be loaded from a GET request to the database as well:

```
 @override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  Provider.of<ConversationsProvider>(context, listen: false).fetchData();
});

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
  (event) {
    String newMsg = event.data['message'];
    Provider.of<ConversationsProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .addNewMessage(ConversationMessage(
            data: newMsg,
            direction: 'Outbound',
            dateCreated: '',
            typeId: 2));
    print('MESSAGE RECEIVED');
    // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
    // messageScreenState.setState(() {
    //   // messagesList.add({'directionName': 'sds', 'data': newMsg});

    // });
  },
);
}


Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {

String newMsg = message.data['message'];
MessageScreen messageScreen = MessageScreen();

Provider.of<ConversationsProvider>(context, listen: false).addNewMessage(ConversationMessage(data: newMsg, direction: 'Outbound', dateCreated: '', typeId: 2));

print("Handling a background message:");
print(message);
```

}

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Container(
  child: Column(children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Center(
          child: _isLoading
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : Consumer<ConversationsProvider>(
                  builder: ((context, value, child) {
                  final messagesList = value.conversations;
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: value.conversations.length,
                      itemBuilder: ((listViewCtx, index) {
                        return MessageBubble(conversationMessage: messagesList.elementAt(index),);
                      }));
                }))
          ),
    ),
    SendMessage()
  ]),
);
}
```

I get an error when I set the FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage() method inside the initState() method of the widget.

```
ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator 
used on a null value
E/flutter (17421): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.registerBackgroundMessageHandler
```

(package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:181:53)
E/flutter (17421): #1      FirebaseMessagingPlatform.onBackgroundMessage= (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_messaging.dart:102:16)
E/flutter (17421): #2      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage (package:firebase_messaging/src/messaging.dart:73:31)
E/flutter (17421): #3      _MessageScreenState.initState (package:webio_appchat_demo/message_screen.dart:83:23)
E/flutter (17421): #4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5015:57)
E/flutter (17421): #5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter (17421): #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter (17421): #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter (17421): #8      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter (17421): #9      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter (17421): #10     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
E/flutter (17421): #11     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter (17421): #12     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter (17421): #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter (17421): #14     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter (17421): #15     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter (17421): #16     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
E/flutter (17421): #17     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter (17421): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter (17421): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter (17421): #20     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter (17421): #21     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter (17421): #22     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
E/flutter (17421): #23     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter (17421): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter (17421): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter (17421): #26     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter (17421): #27     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter (17421): #28     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
E/flutter (17421): #29     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter (17421): #30     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter (17421): #31     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6435:36)
E/flutter (17421): #32     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6447:32)
E/flutter (17421): #33     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter (17421): #34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter (17421): #35     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter (17421): #36     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter (17421): #37     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
E/flutter (17421): #38     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
E/flutter (17421): #39     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
E/flutter (17421): #40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
E/flutter (17421): #41     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
E/flutter (17421): #42     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
E/flutter (17421): #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
E/flutter (17421): #4

Answer (score 0):

```
use @pragma('vm:entry-point') as entrypoint

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
  RemoteMessage message,
) {
String newMsg = message.data['message'];
MessageScreen messageScreen = MessageScreen();

Provider.of<ConversationsProvider>(context, listen: false).addNewMessage(ConversationMessage(data: newMsg, direction: 'Outbound', dateCreated: '', typeId: 2));
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).